# Does the view engine run in the browser part of the MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm curious where the view engine for example Razor runs actually, on the browser part of the server part, or neither?

Comment: Views are processed in server, then generated HTML will passed to client's browser.

Answer (score 0):

When any View is called by action in MVC, browser get view details at server side and then render HTML in DOM client side.